Inferring/Extracting Type from Itself/Own Object using Conditional Types
I currently have these types in my .d.ts.
type TransactionRowTypes = {
    // transaction row types
}
type UserDataTypes = {
    // user data types
}
type InventoryRowTypes = {
    // inventory row types
}

type EventClientEvent = {
    event: 'transactions' | 'userchange' | 'inventory';
    time: number;
    payload: Array<any>;
};

I want to make it so that, for example, when my EventClientEvent.event is transactions, I want the payload to have a type of TransactionRowTypes. If EventClientEvent.event is userchange, I want my payload to have the type of UserDataTypes, and so on. I'm having issues with trying to wrap my head around using conditional typing on its own object type, or if whether I am using this correctly. I have this type extractor, but I'm not sure on how to use it.
type EventName<T extends {event: string}> = T["event"];

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks

Is this approach what you're looking for? If so I'll write up an answer or find a suitable duplication source. If not, what am I missing?

template literal typing can be helpful here, check the example on https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html

Yes that is what I'm looking for. Haven't thought of using keyof being used that way. Please do post an answer and I'll check it, thanks!

@xkeshav interesting,  that can also work. Let me check if I can recreate jcalz answer using this method

Conditional types don't really help with this. It looks like you want EventClientEvent to be a discriminated union of the following form:
type EventClientEvent = {
    event: "transactions";
    time: number;
    payload: TransactionRowTypes[];
} | {
    event: "userchange";
    time: number;
    payload: UserDataTypes[];
} | {
    event: "inventory";
    time: number;
    payload: InventoryRowTypes[];
}
 

You could define that manually, but if you want to be able to add/change event/payload pairings, you can instead write a mapping interface like
interface EventMapping {
  transactions: TransactionRowTypes;
  userchange: UserDataTypes;
  inventory: InventoryRowTypes
}

and then use that to compute EventClientEvent, like this:
type EventClientEvent = { [K in keyof EventMapping]:
  {
    event: K;
    time: number;
    payload: Array<EventMapping[K]>
  }
}[keyof EventMapping]

That's a distributive object type as coined in microsoft/TypeScript#47109 where we make a mapped type and then immediately index into it with the keys of that mapped type. It distributes the inner type {event: K; time: number; payload: Array<EventMapping[K]>} over unions in K, which in this case is keyof EventMapping or "transactions" | "userchange" | "inventory".
You can verify that this evaluates to the equivalent type above.
Playground link to code.
